# awk colum or grep for multiple IP ranges in a file

Tags: awk, range

I have a rather large file and one of the columns is a list of various IP addresses. I have multiple IP ranges I need to print from this file. What's the best way to pull only these ranges. Can it be done in a single statement? For example:

```
10.0.0.0/8
10.102.175.0/28
10.102.231.0/24
10.102.79.0/24
10.102.93.0/30
10.103.141.0/30
10.103.141.0/32
10.103.154.0/26
10.104.152.0/27
10.105.25.0/26
10.107.64.0/24
10.111.130.0/26
10.111.147.0/24
10.111.148.0/24
10.111.149.0/24
10.111.150.0/24
10.27.28.0/24
172.16.208.0/29
172.26.92.0/23
192.1.53.0/24
192.168.16.0/30
192.168.55.0/30
192.200.9.0/24
```

Comment: Is that your file or your expected result? If you just want to extract things that look like IPs, that should be easy; assuming ipv4, it'd be something like `[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\/[0-9]{1,3}`

Comment: the file has actual IP's. The IP's represent different subnets across a WAN. I need to pull a list of IP's from the file that fall within the Ranges I pasted above.

Comment: grepcidr seems to work for me on Debian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grepcidr seems to do what I need.

Answer (score 0):

try GNU ERE Regex:

```
(19[01]|1[0-8][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])|0\.((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])|0\.((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])|0\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[89])))|192\.((1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])|200\.([0-8]\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])|9\.0))
```

It's a single statement (one-liner).